# Logcat is running and collecting device data, however I cannot see it

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm getting a very strange error with the *Android  logcat* view in *Eclipse*. I have a device attached, and have selected it from the *DDMS* perspective, so logcat should be showing messages, however what I see is this:

[image: my view of the logcat]

I know that the *logcat* is receiving data, however, because when I place my mouse over part of the *logcat*, I can see the item:

[image: now with my mouse over the tag field]

Has anyone else encountered this problem? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your workspace.
And as case create a new filter.

Comment: I have restarted Eclipse several times, and removed and re-added the view. Could you be more descriptive about creating a new filter (and how it will help)?

Comment: 1)Focus on logcat 2)press Create filter 3)Create new Name,then Log Tag for example : mainActivity and chose a Log level.4)Then you can see the information in your log filter using Log.i("mainActivity, "YourMessage");

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I updated my Android SDK with the following updates:

- Android SDK Tools, revision 13
- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 7

And now it works like it should.